# Where can I get in-car-camera-data with speed?

Tags: data-request, cars, video

I'm searching in-car-camera data set with vehicle speed at that time. If there is any place where I can get those data free?

Answer (score 2):

The dataset used in the paper ["Learning a Driving Simulator"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.01230) seems to contain what you're after.  The data is 7.25 hours of video files (45 GB compressed; 80 GB decompressed) annotated with measures including speed, acceleration, GPS coordinates, etc.  The data is released under the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 License.  The GitHub repo containing project code, documentation, and a link to the data is https://github.com/commaai/research.  The data itself is hosted at https://archive.org/details/comma-dataset.

> Santana, Eder, and George Hotz. "Learning a driving simulator." arXiv
>   preprint arXiv:1608.01230 (2016).